# Numbers of $2N$ digits that are divisible by the numbers formed by the first and last $N$ digits

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Here's the [problem](https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1385) statement:

> Tyomitch calls the number with $2N$ digits (without leading zeroes)
> "interesting", if it's divisible by both the number formed from its
> first $N$ digits and the number formed from its last $N$ digits.
>
> For example, $1020$ is "interesting" (divisible by $10$ and $20$) and 2005 is not.
>
> Tyomitch wants to know how many "interesting" 2N-digit numbers
> exist. You are to help him.

Despite being a programming problem, it actually has a closed form formula solution, I tried to derive it, but something went wrong since it gives wrong answers for considerably small N.

The solution:

Let $m = a\cdot 10^n + b$, where $n$ is $n$ mentioned in the problem statement and $a, b, n, m \in \mathbb{N}$. $a$ and $b$ are gonna play the role of those two numbers of which we are supposed to divide i.e. $a \mid m$ and $b \mid m$. So we also need to put some constraints on them, like we can't have leading zeros in number $m$ and we also can't have zeros in $a$ or $b$ since we would have divided by zero. So, firstly let do these constraints:
$$10^{n - 1} \leq a < 10^n$$
$$1 \leq b < 10^n$$
Now let's do some observations:
$$a \mid m \Leftrightarrow m = a \cdot v$$
$$m = a \cdot 10^n + b \Leftrightarrow m - a \cdot 10^n = b \Leftrightarrow a \cdot v - a \cdot 10^n = b\Leftrightarrow a(v - 10^n) = b  \Leftrightarrow a \mid b$$
$$a \mid b \Leftrightarrow b \geq a$$
Then we have more tight constraints for b:
$$10^{n - 1} \leq a \leq b < 10^n$$
$$a \mid b \Leftrightarrow b = a \cdot k, \text{ where } k < 10$$
Back to the original equation:
$$m = a \cdot 10^n + b \Leftrightarrow \frac{m}{b} = \frac{a \cdot 10^n + b}{b} 
\Leftrightarrow \frac{m}{b} = \frac{a \cdot 10^n}{a\cdot k} + 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{m}{b} = \frac{10^n}{k} + 1 \Leftrightarrow k \mid 10^n \text{  since LHS is integer}$$
There are 3 corner cases:
$$n = 1, k \in \{1, 2, 5\}$$
$$n = 2, k \in \{1, 2, 4, 5\}$$
$$n \geq 3, k \in \{1, 2, 4, 5, 8\}$$

I'll be looking only to the third case since I'm looking for general formula.

Lemma:
Amount of multiples of $k$ on $[1; n]$ segment is equal to $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$

Let's denote $p_{k}(n)$ = $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$ i.e. amount of multiples of $k$ on $[1; n]$ and $p_k(a, b)$ - amount of multiples of $k$ on $[a; b]$ i.e. $p_k(a, b) = p_k(b) - p_k(a - 1)$.

Since we have those constraints:
$$10^{n - 1} \leq a < 10^n$$
$$10^{n - 1} \leq b < 10^n$$
$$10^{n - 1} \leq a\cdot k < 10^n$$
We need to count amount of multiples of $k$ in $[10^{n - 1}, 10^{n} - 1]$ segment for all possible $k$ i.e. $k \in \{1, 2, 4, 5, 8\}$ and that's gonna be the answer.

$p_k(10^{n - 1} - 1, 10^{n} - 1) \Leftrightarrow p_k(10^{n - 1}, 10^n)$ for $n \geq 4$, since $10^n$ adds one mupltiply for each possible divisor $(1, 2, 4, 5, 8)$. Same goes for $10^{n - 1}$ negating the added divisors. Therefore the answer for amount of "interesting" numbers for given $n$ is:

$$p_1(10^{n - 1}, 10^n) + p_2(10^{n - 1}, 10^n) + p_4(10^{n - 1}, 10^n) + p_5(10^{n - 1}, 10^n) + p_8(10^{n - 1}, 10^n) = $$
$$= \frac{1}{1}10^n - \frac{1}{1} 10^{n - 1} + \frac{1}{2}10^n - \frac{1}{2} 10^{n - 1} + \frac{1}{4}10^n - \frac{1}{4} 10^{n - 1}+ \frac{1}{5}10^n - \frac{1}{5} 10^{n - 1}+ \frac{1}{8}10^n - \frac{1}{8} 10^{n - 1} = $$
$$= 10^n\bigg(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{10}\bigg(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{8}\bigg)\bigg) =$$
$$= \frac{747}{400}\cdot 10^n = 1.8675 \cdot 10^n$$

Which is a not correct formula. You may ask why is it wrong? I have bruteforced this problem for small $n$ up to $4$. For $n = 3$ I should have had $1575$ and for $n = 4 - 15750$. Which makes formula more like $1.575 \cdot 10^n$. And I wonder what and where went wrong?

P.S. I remembered my yesterday idea when I was trying to figure out $n = 2$ case:

As before I need to count amount of all possible $k \in \{1, 2, 4, 5\}$.
$$10 \leq a\cdot k < 100$$

The ans is (by division I mean floored division): $\frac{99}{1} + \frac{99}{2} + \frac{99}{4} + \frac{99}{5} - (\frac{9}{1} + \frac{9}{1} + \frac{9}{1} + \frac{9}{1}) = 99 + 49 + 24 + 19 - 36 = 155$, which IS a correct answer for $n = 2$. I completely don't remember how I derived this equation, though now I think it was a complete fluke idea which led me to right answer.

What's more interesting if I do the same for general formula equation it is indeed leading to the right answer too.

$$10^n\bigg(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{10}\bigg(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1}\bigg)\bigg) =$$
$$= \frac{63}{40}\cdot 10^n = 1.575 \cdot 10^n$$

But still I want to know what went wrong with my initial solution since I don't know at all how to derive the correct formula.

Comment: +1 : For a nicely presented question, with nice work shown.  I would like to anticipate/deflect MathSE reviewer criticisms for your linking to a problem statement, rather than converting the statement to MathJax, or attempting to embed the statement into the posting as an image.  Often, the OP (i.e. original poster) will mis-translate the question.  When MathSE reviewers grapple with a tricky question, they always have to wonder whether pertinent info has been omitted or misinterpreted.  Personally, I am glad that the OP provided the link, because this immediately resolves reviewer concerns.

Comment: "...we also can't have zeros in a or b since we would have divided by zero" : I am unsure whether this is true.  I am assuming that you intend that while $(a)$ and $(b)$ can have embedded zeroes, they can't have leading zeroes (on the left hand side).  Assuming so, for $(a)$, this is true by the explicit problem description.  For $(b)$, I see no obvious reason that $(b)$ can not have leading zeroes.  Perhaps I am overlooking something.  Please explain, and also, please explain what you intend by : "since we would have divided by zero".

Comment: @user2661923 Let's consider 1000 for example. Then I should divide 1000 by 10 and by 0 which is a not right thing to do. Also by "leading zeros" I mean I can't have number like 0110 so I put constraint on $a$ to be greater then $10^{n - 1}$

Comment: It just hit me, why $(b)$ can't have leading zeroes.  Unsure if this is rigorous.  Anyway, consider $100010$.  Since $(b = 010)$, you end up with $(a = 100)$ not dividing the number, since $(a)$ does not divide $(b)$.  This seems right, but I am unsure if it is right.

Comment: @user2661923 yeah, you're right, but initially I'm talking about "leading zeros" only for $a$, later after $a | b$ observation, it'll get clear why $b$ can't have "leading zeros" too. (talking about leading zeros for b is a little confusing but what I wanted to say, that for the first N digits number can't have first digit as zero, and the same goes for the last N digits but it can be concluded after $a \mid b$ observation)

Comment: Please change the tag to  `elementary-number-theory`

Comment: FWIW, for N=1 to 4, my computer implementation counts 14, 208, 2324, and 24186 "interesting" numbers.  Surprisingly, this sequence isn't on OEIS yet.

Comment: My bad: I didn't implement the "without leading zeroes" rule.  Corrected sequence is 14, 155, 1575, 15750.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $n\ge 3$.

A pair $(a,b)$ qualifies if and only if $b=ka$ for some $k\in\{1,2,4,5,8\}$, subject to 
the constraints
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
10^{n-1}\le &a < 10^n\\[4pt]
10^{n-1}\le &b < 10^n\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Since $b=ka$ for some $k\in\{1,2,4,5,8\}$, the qualifying pairs $(a,b)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with pairs $(k,b)$ where $k{\,\mid\,}b$, subject to the single constraint
$$
k10^{n-1}\le b < 10^n
$$
Then for each $k\in\{1,2,4,5,8\}$, the qualifying values of $b$ consist of all multiples of $k$ from $k\cdot 10^{n-1}$ up to but not including $10^n$, hence the number of interesting numbers is
$$
\sum_{\!\!\!k\in\{1,2,4,5,8\}}\!\!\!\Bigl(\frac{10^n}{k}-10^{n-1}\Bigr)
$$
which can be simplified to $1575\cdot 10^{n-3}$.

As regards your error, you have the inequality
$$
10^{n - 1} \le a\cdot k < 10^n
$$
which should be strengthened to
$$
k\cdot 10^{n - 1} \le a\cdot k < 10^n
$$

Comment: I have very vague feelings. After some thinking, I completely understand now the $k\cdot 10^{n - 1}$ lower bound, but still don't understand which numbers did I accidentally added which should be not in the answer

Comment: I figured it out, I counted numbers like "050100", a = 50, b = 100, k = 2. But it's surely not a valid number. So I need to put $k\cdot10^{n - 1}$ constraint. I liked @gnasher729 idea how to do it rigorously, but I'm not sure how to do it more naturally.

Comment: After some thought this constraint seem to me already natural, though I don't know why I didn't spot it in the first place, so I guess I completely understood the idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = a10^n + b$, $n \geq 1$.

$b$ divides $a10^n + b$, so $b \not= 0$ divides $a10^n$.

$a$ divides $a10^n +b$, so $a$ divides $b$.

$x$ has no leading zeroes. $b \geq a$ because $a$ divides $b \not= 0$. Together $10^{n-1} \leq a \leq b < 10^n$.

$b$ equals a multiplied by an integer from $1$ to $9$. But since $b$ divides $a10^n$ we have $b = a \cdot f$ with $f = 1, 2, 4, 5,$ or $8$.

We must have $n \geq 1$; $f = 4$ requires $n \geq 2$ and $f = 8$ requires $n \geq 3$. The values of $a$ are $10^{n-1} \leq a < 10^n / f$, which is $10^n \cdot (1/f - 1/10)$ values. For $f = 1, 2, 4, 5, 8$ this is $10^n$, multiplied by $0.9, 0.4, 0.15, 0.1$ and $0.025$.

For $n = 1$ the sum of the factors is $1.4$. For $n = 2$ it is $1.55$, and for $n \geq 3$ it is $1.575$.

So $14$ with $n=1$, $155$ with $n= 2$, and $1.575 \times 10^n$ with $n \geq 3$.

The mistake in the original solution is that with some $f$, the upper limitations are $b=af < 10^n$ and therefore $a < 10^n / f$, but the lower limit is just $a \geq 10^n / 10$, so the factor $f$ doesn’t go into the lower bound.